# HttpSendRequest takes 10sec to get the response in my customer's PC, but works well in mine about 2sec

Tags: api, https, delphi-7, wininet

It's a Https Post:
In some PC, the API HttpSendRequest works well, but sometimes it's going to take about 10s to get the response. I coded it in Delphi, and the same thing happens in c# code.
I Changed the Url, but it's all the same.
Plz help me, regards~

Comment: Not clear if a slow PC and a fast PC are on the same LAN. I suspect that the internet connection are slower on some. Use Tracert on each PC to check how long a simple packet takes to reach the target server. Also verify that a "security product" is not inspecting the HTTP traffic and slow things down.

Comment: Have you tried attaching a status callback to the HTTP session and check for delays between the various stage(s)?

Comment: @fpiette Thank u for your answer. Ping is ok and in fact  the test has been done before asking the question. The problem has been resolved and the key is IE's setting. The option is  IE->Internet option->connection->LAN->Autoconfig->Autocheckconfig， set it unchecked. Because  in windows , the work of searching for proxy is the  way that the API works. Thank u again.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm not good at using http tools to do what you said, but the problem is solved and it's IE's setting option, thank u.

Comment: @James a status callback is part of the same WinInet API that `HttpSendRequest` comes from, see [InternetSetStatusCallback()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetsetstatuscallback).